# How to wait for WebBrowser control in C#

Tags: c#, flash, browser

I'm trying to remove `<object>` tags that are injected by JavaScript into the page. When the WebBrowser's DocumentCompleted event is called, the flash content has not been injected yet. I tried implementing Thread.Sleep and waiting for a timer but they all seem to "hog" the process, stopping the web browser control from rendering. Is there a way to wait for a short period of time (5 seconds or so) that allows the web browser to continue to execute JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(....) in UI thread, use
something like that:

```
DateTime maxWaitTimeout = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(5);
while (DateTime.Now < maxWaitTimeout)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
    /// now check required element and call 'break' if needed
}
```

Comment: a day with no success and then found this answer... Works perfectly